# Tires on Honda Odyssey

Tags: tires

I currently have a 2004 Honda Odyssey and need some winter tires for it. Currently the tire size for my van is 225/60/r16. My father-in-law has a set of winter tires on rims but they are a 225/65/r16. Will they work on my van or are they too big for my van?

Comment: That's pretty close, and they should work. But the real question is: will the rims bolt up to the Honda? That is, do your FIL's rims have the same bolt pattern and offset as the rims on your Honda?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a good resource for tire sizing:

[Tire Size Calculator](https://tiresize.com/calculator/)

The larger 225/65 tires are only larger by 0.9" diameter which means less then 0.5" of reduced clearance.  (The radius of the tire is 0.45" larger than the smaller one.)

Unless the clearance on your Odyssey is unusually small, there should be no problem fitting these tires to your car.

The rims, however, are another story.  Generally rims from different makes and models do not interchange due to different bolt sizes, bolt count, and bolt-circle diameter.  It would be a simple matter to check and see if they fit.  Otherwise you can take them to a tire shop and have them remounted on your Odyssey wheels, balanced, and fitted to your vehicle.